# Different methods yielding different answers in combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How many $4$ digit numbers can be formed by using the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ if at least one digit is repeated?

## Method 1:

Complement rule: 
$7^4 - ^7P_4= 1561 $ // Correct answer.

## Method 2:

Making cases and solving:

1) One digit is repeated.

Let's say $7$ repeats twice.
 Now we have 6 numbers and we have to choose 2. Multiply by $4!$ to obtain number of permutations of the 4 numbers.

And then we'll divide by $2!$ to exclude the permutations of $7$s among themselves.

But this can happen with all our 7 digits so we'll also multiply by 7.

In numbers this means:

$$\dfrac{7 \times \dbinom62 \times 4!}{2!}= 1260$$

2) 3 digits same, 1 digit different:

$$\dfrac{7 \times 4! \times \dbinom{6}{1}}{3!}= 168 $$

3) All digits same , 
clearly there are $7$ ways.

4) 2 digits same, 2 digits same (example: 2233)

$\dfrac{\dbinom{7}{1} \dbinom 6 1 \times 4!}{2!\times 2!}$= 252

Adding the results of the above cases gives, $1687$// Wrong answer.

Please tell me the error in the second method.

Comment: 6 numbers and we have to choose 2?  it is 3! @Abcd

Comment: @XcoderX This is not true. We are still permuting $4$ digits, then dividing out by the number of permutations of the repeated digit. See the multinomial coefficient.

Comment: @ml0105 why?  there are 3 more number slots

Comment: All four digits need to be permuted. Count the number of permutations of $1, 1, 2, 3$ by hand. Does that match up with the Case 1 answer or your analysis?

Comment: Yes I understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the case 4)

You have to choose 2 digits among 7: then it is $\dfrac{{7 \choose 2} \times 4!}{2!\times 2!}=126$.

And you get finally $126+168+126+7=1561$.

Indeed you have to choose **simultaneously** the two digits. With your computation you act like you choose the first digit, **then** the second one, whereas there is no "first" or "second" digit. To say it in a different manner you consider the sets {1,3} and {3,1} as different (you counted each one once).